Invariance of general equations under Lorentz Transformation
I was reading Quantum Field Theory by Peskin and Schroeder. On page number 37 He mentions

"In general, any equation in which each term has the same set of uncontracted Lorentz indices will naturally be invariant under Lorentz transformations."

My question is how does one prove this claim?

I'll try to answer this. It might be inadequate but maybe a little useful.
If there is an equation $A^\mu = B^\mu$ then the equation holds true in any frame, which is a postulate of special relativity. Thus a transformation from one frame to another would affect the R.H.S. and L.H.S. in a way that maintains the equality in this new frame too.

Ahh, now I see. Thanks

Could you please tick the green mark if it has answered the question? Thanks :)
